# is it true that if you join Islam you can't leave it anymore or you face death penalty?

Tags: sharia, conversion

Reading about Islam I found this in Wikipedia

> Leaving Islam is a sin and a religious crime. Once any man or woman is
>   officially classified as Muslim, because of birth or religious
>   conversion, he or she will be subject to the death penalty if he or
>   she becomes an apostate, that is, abandons his or her faith in Islam
>   in order to become an atheist, agnostic or to convert to another
>   religion. Before executing the death penalty, sharia demands that the
>   individual be offered one chance to return to Islam.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharia

is it true that if you join Islam you can't leave it anymore or you face death penalty?

Comment: **<comments deleted>** Comments are intended for constructive criticism and seeking clarification, not for argument and debate.

Comment: This is only in Islamic states with Penalty death, but now there are one Islamic state I guess? But in Muslim countries, it no longer happens this. This punishment is up to God. He is the one that has the right to punish, not us.